# Save and display images on Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: flask, google-app-engine

I am currently developping an Flask application that dynamically generated images. I save the image to static/img folder.

But the image is never changed after first time created.

Any body know what the issue behind.

many thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more information such as - 1) Are you using GAE Flex or GAE Standard 2) How are you saving to static/img folder? 3) Are you saving using the same file name 4) How do you know the image is not changed

Comment: Thanks for commentting. (1) I am deploying to Flex. (2) I saved using plt.savefig('filename.png').  (4) I can view the image using its full url, can not changes after updates.

Comment: The only way to change static files is to redeploy your app.  You can't change static files dynamically in a production app.  To dynamically change images, you need to save the images in a datastore or google cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a caching issue (especially since you're saving to a static folder). Try appending a dummy query parameter e.g <your_url>/?123. If you see the new file, then it's a caching issue. One quick and dirty fix would be to generate unique values and append to the url or you can look up cache bursting techniques for GAE